# recursive images with jQuery each()

Tags: jquery

I have to create a automatic slideshow with images, I would like to put every image in a different position into the body tag, so I have created one div for every image. 
I'm using jQuery each() to show all the images

```
<div id="img1" class="images" ><img  src="img/works/img1.jpg"/></div>
<div id="img2" class="images" ><img src="img/works/img2.jpg"/></div>
...


<script>
var arr = ["img1", "img2",..., "img22" ];

var $fade_in=1500;

$.each(arr, function images(i) {
$("#" + this).delay(i*1000).show($fade_in);
});     
</script>
```

It works. Now, how can I obtain the function recursive? I need a infinite loop

I have seen those links, 
http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/F6nJu/1/
http://jsfiddle.net/JJfKM/138/
but I can't apply they in my code.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setInterval()` to repeatedly run the slides forever.

```
function runSlides() {
    var index = 0;
    var imgList$ = $(".images");

    setInterval(function () {
        // hide previous slide
        imgList$.eq(index).hide(1500);
        // show next slide
        ++index;
        if (index >= imgList$.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
        imgList$.eq(index).show(1500);
    }, 2500);    
}
```

And, the at some point in your code, you would call this by using:

```
runSlides();
```

In this example, I've hidden the previous slide and shown the next one on each interval which isn't something you did in your example, but I figure you have to do something like that to get it to repeat over and over again.

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4STRU/.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I also need to hide image after have shown it, but it doesn't work for me. 
Images are in their position but all togheter, not one after the other.

Comment: @user1275857 - were you asking me a question?  I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: @Franziska - correct, in my example, I use jQuery to generate the list of images directly from the page so no array is needed.

Comment: Ok, the place fot the answer should be right, probably you can't understand my english. I said that trying your code, it doesn't work.
I can't have a delay between one image and the other, the images appear together at the same moment

Comment: @Franziska: You're allowed to modify the code to suit your needs.

Comment: @Franziska - you can see a slightly modified version working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4STRU/.

Comment: Your first reply was perfect, but you missed to add "runSlides();"
And I am not so expert to understand it immediatly.
Thank you so much for the help. 
It works exactly as I wanted.

Grazie per l'aiuto :)

Comment: @Franziska - since you're new on StackOverflow, do you understand that when you ask a question and you get helpful answers, you should indicate which answer was the most helpful by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer (right below the number and up/down arrows)?  This indicates to the SO community which answer helped you the most (the best answer) and it earns you some reputation points (which may result in you earning more privileges later) and it rewards the answerer with some reputation points for helping you.